# Receiving error invalid literal for int() and ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead..') midway through?

Tags: python, python-requests, request, urllib

I'm using an API &requests library to read some data at a set cadence each day, and everythings been working until recently.
All of a sudden am getting an error midway reading data:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    
ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

This doesn't happen sporadically; when I'm trying to read the data I get this error about an hour in..online I'm seeing its server/network related. But I'm not sure how to confirm this or check that there's not something I can do to solution it.

```
url = "https://api...."
dflist=[]
for i in range (0,variable1):


  with open("/dbfs/tmp/file{}.json".format(i+1)) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data1=json.dumps(data) 
    payload=str(data).encode("utf-8") 
    headers = {
      'content-type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      'cache-control': "no-cache",

        }
    #response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    with requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers) as response:
      print("RESPONSE: ", response)
      for j in range(20):

        geturl= str(response.text)
        getresponse = requests.request("GET", geturl)
        if getresponse.status_code!=200:
          time.sleep(20)# wait 20 seconds 
          j=j+1

        else:
          jsondata=getresponse.text
          jdata=json.loads(jsondata)
          df=pd.DataFrame(jdata)
          print("df length")
          print(len(df))
          dflist.append(df)
          break

  i=i+1
```

Also, I'd appreciate if someone could give advice on how to troubleshoot something like this? I don't work with APIs and url requests often, so not sure of the basics to check in this situation